# how do I get text value outside of any tag in html, through selenium in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have text,which is not enclosed inside any of the HTML tag but is wrapped in between two HTML tag as shown in below image, how do I get the value 38 in this case, through selenium in java.

[image]

below is my code, which I tried but it's only giving the label value of `<b>` attribute and not the desired value i.e. **38** in this case

```
String ageAtAdmission=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@name='profile']//b[4]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  AR_Utils.logMsg("Age at Admission "+ageAtAdmission);
```

**OUTPUT :**
Age at Admisson Age at Admission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get particular textNode value of a DOM with Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33089/how-do-i-get-particular-textnode-value-of-a-dom-with-selenium)

Comment: You have to remember that the text you're looking for **IS** enclosed in an HTML tag.  It might be the <body> or even in the <HTML> tag.  Find _that_ element, then you should be able to get the text attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to get the text of the parent anchor (`//a[@name="profile"]/text()`) you would find that the text you are seeking is contained within the string that's returned.

You'd get a string that contains something like

```
DEGREE : Age at Admission : 38 : PA Candidate :
```

The number of spaces between text entries could be different, but if you used a standard string library function to remove any spaces, you'd then have a string containing the following:

```
DEGREE:AgeatAdmission:38:PACandidate:
```

Since age at admission and PA Candidate are static text, you can then use the standard substring functions to strip off everything before your target text (`38`) and everything after. Or you could simply use the standard string split function to turn your string into an array. In C# or Java it would probably look something like `string[] mystringarray = String.Split(':', mystring);`

Then you find the index of the element with value `"AgeatAdmission"`, go to the next element, and you have your value.

Comment: Ultimately, I used the same functions as you suggested above & it was working.Thanks though.