# How can I verify that saved data is displayed corrrectly using Selenium + C#?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

```
<p class="details-info-block__text"><span class="details-info-block__label">Business Address 1:</span> 1010 Priority Way West Dr</p>
```

I want to verify the address value (e.g. "1010 Priority Way West Dr"). But retrieving it using XPath `//span[contains(text(), 'Business Address 1')]/..` returns the following string

> Business Address 1: 1010 Priority Way West Dr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get particular textNode value of a DOM with Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33089/how-do-i-get-particular-textnode-value-of-a-dom-with-selenium)

Comment: you are using //span where the text in the span is 'Business Address 1' if you used //p you could try and get the text from that

Answer (score 1):

- You get a string, and you know what that string should end with.
- There is
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netframework-4.8
- You can use that, it's probably enough.
- If you know the allowed variations of Business Address 1: then you can remove those from the string.
- Maybe you know that your answer should always be after the first semi colon

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all inner text of `<p class="details-info-block__text">` and then parse out the required text using String-related toolset of C#. It will be quite a tricky thing to extract what you want using selenium since the latter piece of text is a separate "naked" text node in a DOM and Selenium cannot parse it to a dedicated `WebElement` (anything having no associated tag)